# Php array_merge to one result

Tags: php, arrays

How to combine all the arrays into one total result?
now the results with echo like 252 299 i need get total result 252+299 and get from echo 551

```
<?php
    $videoListt = array_merge($topchan1["items"],$topchan2["items"]);
    for( $i= 0 ; $i <= count($videoListt)-1 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $videoListt[$i]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Martynas, welcome to StackOverflow. Usually it's a good idea to show some code that you've already tried to solve your problem, and explain why it's not working and what you expect it should do - then people can help to explain why your code isn't working. This question is unclear about the expected result and doesn't show what you've already tried (and probably spent a long time on!)

Comment: edited question code working but i need combine in one total result.

Comment: Difficult to answer closed questions. However, I think you should add the values in the loop and echo the result, instead of echoing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment a variable from within each iteration of your loop, then output it at the end:

```
$subscriberCount = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($videoListt) - 1; $i++) {
    $subscriberCount += $videoListt[$i]['statistics']['subscriberCount'];
}
echo $subscriberCount;
```